# Generating API documentation from Java Cloud Endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, swagger, apiblueprint, raml

I'm looking for an efficient way to generate API documentation in a readable format, from the generated files from Cloud Endpoint (Java). The generated files are either:
- my_api.api
- my_api*.discovery

Something that looks like this:
- https://github.com/kevinrenskers/raml2html#example-output

Swagger, API blueprint and RAML are all nice options, but don't seem adapt well to endpoint generated API descriptor files.

What methods are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we (Apiary) do not actually offer any code generation tool at the moment for API Blueprint.

If you are looking for a way how to generate a description of your API from the code then API Blueprint isn't probably the best choice as we believe it should represent the contract between everybody involved in the API design lifecycle. This is also the reason why we have built the testing tool – Dredd – https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd

With Dredd you can test your API implementation is matching to your blueprint. It wouldn't make much sense if the blueprint would be generated from the implementation.

Hope it clarifies.